# How can I refactor this Ruby method to run faster?

Tags: arrays, ruby

The method below is supposed to take an array `a` and return the duplicated integer whose second index value is the lowest. The array will only include integers between 1 and `a.length`. With this example,

```
firstDuplicate([1,2,3,2,4,5,1])
```

the method returns `2`.

```
def firstDuplicate(a)
    num = 1
    big_num_array = []
    a.length.times do
        num_array = []
        if a.include?(num)
            num_array.push(a.index(num))
            a[a.index(num)] = "x"
            if a.include?(num)
                num_array.unshift(a.index(num))
                num_array.push(num)
            end
            big_num_array.push(num_array) if num_array.length == 3
         end        
         num += 1   
     end
     if big_num_array.length > 0
         big_num_array.sort![0][2]
     else
         -1
     end  
end
```

The code works, but seems longer than necessary and doesn't run fast enough. I am looking for ways to refactor this.

Comment: BTW, the experts for "code that works but could be more readable and/or faster" are over at [codereview.se]. Should you decide that your question finds a better home there, please make sure to read the help center, on-topic and off-topic pages, the FAQ and if unsure ask on their meta page or in chat, just like you would on any other site. (In other words: don't take my word for it.) They have some specific rules about what code can be posted and how. (For example, [so] prefers that you condense your production code down to a [mcve], whereas [codereview.se] prefers the *real* code in context.)

Comment: Also, should you decide to do this, don't cross-post, rather delete this question, or even better, ask a moderator to migrate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could count the entries as you go and use `Enumerable#find` to stop iterating as soon as you find something again:

```
h = { }
a.find do |e|
  h[e] = h[e].to_i + 1 # The `to_i` converts `nil` to zero without a bunch of noise.
  h[e] == 2
end
```

You could also say:

```
h = Hash.new(0) # to auto-vivify with zeros
a.find do |e|
  h[e] += 1
  h[e] == 2
end
```

or use `Hash#fetch` with a default value:

```
h = { }
a.find do |e|
  h[e] = h.fetch(e, 0) + 1
  h[e] == 2
end
```

`find` will stop as soon as it finds an element that makes that block `true` so this should be reasonably efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways that could be done quite simply.

**Use a set**

```
require 'set'

def first_dup(arr)
  st = Set.new
  arr.find { |e| st.add?(e).nil? }
end

first_dup [1,2,3,2,4,5,4,1,4]
  #=> 2
first_dup [1,2,3,4,5]
  #=> nil
```

See [Set#add?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F).

**Use `Array#difference`**

```
def first_dup(arr)
  arr.difference(arr.uniq).first
end

first_dup [1,2,3,2,4,5,4,1,4]
  #=> 2
first_dup [1,2,3,4,5]
  #=> nil
```

I have found `Array#difference` to be sufficiently useful that I [proposed it be added to the Ruby core](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11815) (but it doesn't seem to be gaining traction). It is as follows:

```
class Array
  def difference(other)
    h = other.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }
    reject { |e| h[e] > 0 && h[e] -= 1 }
  end
end
```

As explained at the link, it differs from [Array#-](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-2D) as follows:

```
a = [1,2,2,3,3,2,2]
b = [2,2,3]

a - b
  #=> [1]
a.difference(b)
  #=> [1,3,2,2]
```

That is, `difference` "removes" one `2`in `a` for each `2` in `b` (similar for `3`), preserving the order of what's left of `a`. `a` is not mutated, however.

The steps in the example given above for the present problem are as follows.

```
arr = [1,2,3,2,4,5,4,1,4]
a = arr.uniq
  #=> [1,2,3,4,5]
b = arr.difference(a)
  #=> [2, 4, 1, 4]
b.first
  #=> 2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for super performance, ruby is probably not a best language of choice. If you are looking for a readability, here you go:

```
[1,2,3,2,4,5,1].
  map.               # or each (less readable, probably faster) 
  with_index.
  group_by(&:shift). # or group_by(&:first)
  min_by { |v, a| a[1] && a[1].last || Float::INFINITY }.
  first
#⇒ 2
```